# Remove accept from form input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to change a url input into a file input and vice-versa when user clicks radio button.

When I try to remove the accept attribute from the input, I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).removeAttr is not a function

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('change', function(event) {

  if (this.id === 'radio-rss-feed') {
    //// Change file input to url input


    //// input
    $('#feed-file').get(0).type = 'url';
    $('#feed-file').get(0).name = 'feed-url';

    //// THIS GETS ERROR
    $('#feed-file').get(0).removeAttr('accept');

    $('#feed-file').get(0).id = 'feed-url';

    ////label
    $('#feed-url').prev().get(0).htmlFor = 'feed-url';
    $('#feed-url').prev().get(0).textContent = 'Feed URL'

  } else if (this.id === 'radio-rss-file') {
    //// change url input to file input

    //// input
    $('#feed-url').get(0).type = 'file';
    $('#feed-url').get(0).name = 'feed-file';
    $('#feed-url').get(0).accept = ".rss,text/xml"
    $('#feed-url').get(0).id = 'feed-file';

    ////label 
    $('#feed-file').prev().get(0).htmlFor = 'feed-file';
    $('#feed-file').prev().get(0).textContent = 'Feed File'

  } else {

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post' id='rss-post-form'>
  /// INPUT
  <div class="mb-3" id="rss-input-div">
    <label for='feed-url' class='form-label'>Feed URL</label>
    <input class='form-control' id='feed-url' name='feed-url' type='url'>
  </div>

  //// RADIO
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="feed-form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio-rss" id="radio-rss-feed" checked>
    <label for="radio-rss-feed" class="form-check-label">Rss Feed</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="file-form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio-rss" id="radio-rss-file">
    <label for="radio-rss-file" class="form-check-label">Rss File</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is because `get()` returns an Element object, not a jQuery object. To do what you need, change `get(0)` to `eq(0`). ***However*** you're selecting the elements by `id`, therefore there should only ever be a single instance of each element with that `id`, so there's no point using `get()`/`eq()` at all. If you have multiple elements with the same `id` then that's an error you need to correct by changing the id to a class. Finally, I'd suggest that a better, more reliable approach, would be to have the text and file inputs present in the DOM, then just hide/show them as necessary.

Comment: When you use .get(0) you end up with the HTMLElement, not the jQuery object. Which means you cannot use jQuery functions any longer. Use .eq(0) instead, or use .removeAttribute() (also please do basic debugging first, like console.log() stuff to check what you're dealing with)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, since they set properties on HTMLElement itself, they do need use `get(0)`, without it, they would have to use jquery functions to set properties.

Comment: That's correct - but if you're going to do that why bother with jQuery at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so hens the answer:

It's because it's not `removeAttr()` but `removeAttribute()`

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('change', function(event){

  if (this.id === 'radio-rss-feed'){
    //// Change file input to url input
    
    
    //// input
    $('#feed-file').get(0).type = 'url';
    $('#feed-file').get(0).name = 'feed-url';
    
    //// THIS GETS ERROR
    $('#feed-file').get(0).removeAttribute('accept');

    $('#feed-file').get(0).id = 'feed-url';

    ////label
    $('#feed-url').prev().get(0).htmlFor = 'feed-url';
    $('#feed-url').prev().get(0).textContent = 'Feed URL'
    
  } else if (this.id === 'radio-rss-file'){
    //// change url input to file input
    
    //// input
    $('#feed-url').get(0).type = 'file';
    $('#feed-url').get(0).name = 'feed-file';
    $('#feed-url').get(0).accept = ".rss,text/xml"
    $('#feed-url').get(0).id = 'feed-file';
    
    ////label 
    $('#feed-file').prev().get(0).htmlFor = 'feed-file';
    $('#feed-file').prev().get(0).textContent = 'Feed File'
    
  } else {

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post' id='rss-post-form'>
    /// INPUT
    <div class="mb-3" id="rss-input-div">
        <label for='feed-url' class='form-label'>Feed URL</label>
        <input class='form-control' id='feed-url' name='feed-url' type='url'>
    </div>

    //// RADIO
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="feed-form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio-rss" id="radio-rss-feed" checked>
      <label for="radio-rss-feed" class="form-check-label">Rss Feed</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="file-form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radio-rss" id="radio-rss-file">
      <label for="radio-rss-file" class="form-check-label">Rss File</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

And avoid calling same functions over and over again, execute it once and store it's result in a variable instead:

```
$('.form-check-input').on('change', function(event){

  //// input
  const input = $('#feed-file').get(0);
  //// label
  const label = $('#feed-url').prev().get(0);

  if (this.id === 'radio-rss-feed'){
    //// Change file input to url input

    input.type = 'url';
    input.name = 'feed-url';

    //// THIS GETS ERROR
    input.removeAttribute('accept');

    input.id = 'feed-url';

    ////label
    label.htmlFor = 'feed-url';
    label.textContent = 'Feed URL'
    
  } else if (this.id === 'radio-rss-file'){
    //// change url input to file input
    
    //// input
    input.type = 'file';
    input.name = 'feed-file';
    input.accept = ".rss,text/xml"
    input.id = 'feed-file';
    
    ////label 
    label.htmlFor = 'feed-file';
    label.textContent = 'Feed File'
    
  } else {

  }
})
```